# $.post to php file in Amazon EC2 doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post, amazon-ec2

i have test.html and test.php file uploaded to /var/www/html in my AWS Amazon EC2

URL of test.html is : **http://ec2-11-11-111-11.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/test.html**

URL of test.php is: **http://ec2-11-11-111-11.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/test.php**

test.html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        function myFunction(){
            var url = "http://ec2-11-11-111-11.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/test.php";
            var data = "test_data_string"; 

            alert("Post to PHP"); //check to see if javascript is working

            $.post(url, {testdata:data},
                        function(echo){alert(echo);});
            }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

test.php is:

```
<?php
   $data = $_POST['testdata'];
   echo "success";
?>
```

I am expecting to get alert("success"); when I click the "click me" button, but I am getting nothing.

i get **alert("Post to PHP");** when I click on the button. so it seems that both of the files are working except $.post();
What am i doing wrong here??

Comment: Have you tired with including JQuery latest file in script tag ? Take a look on this example : http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **These two urls are not accessible** , I am not sure what you are doing but *putting the php file online does not mean that it is  accessible and will run as a script.*
   URL1: http://ec2-11-11-111-11.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/test.html

   URL2: http://ec2-11-11-111-11.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/test.php
2. Include **jQuery** library

*update:*
Your js does not have problem if you include the jquery library. I tested it sends the post request successfully. [`jsFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/sojazpuz/)